# How to keep endnotes right after the text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working with a long document in Word divided in sections, where the endnotes are at the end of each section. It seems that, when the endnotes do not fit right after the end of the main text, they are ALL moved into the next page, leaving an empty space at the end of the section:

[image: Screen capture]

Is it possible to have them right after?

Comment: Try : select your footnote, right-click and press Paragraph, Line and Page Breaks tab, uncheck "Keep lines together", press "Set as Default" and then OK.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I checked "Keep lines together" and it worked!

Comment: Good - I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to
select the endnote, right-click and press Paragraph,
Line and Page Breaks tab, then check "Keep lines together",
press "Set as Default" (if required) and then OK.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).